# Java design pattern to check for integer sign

Tags: java, design-patterns

I come from C++ to Java, and, needless to say, certain things seem a bit unnatural (relative to my C++ background). For example, Java does not have unsigned numeric types. So I am curious whether there is a best, or conventional way, to check for sign in certain situations.

For example, suppose I'm designing a dynamic array class. I would like to keep track of the size of the array, which I can declare as

`private int length`

In case an array needs to be resized, it should be resized by a set `block_size`, so I should also have

`private int block_size`

Now, I should allow the user to set `block_size`, and I should certainly have something like

```
public void setValueAt(int pos) { ... }
public void setBlockSize(int bsize) { ... }
```

Now, because we do not have unsigned numeric types, and because -- in the best practices of OOD -- the objects should be consistent, I should guard against errors like `setValueAt(-1)`.

The obvious way is a simple `if` conditional check. One could argue that I could simply let it slide, since at the point the array is referenced, Java will complain about the negative index and throw a compile-time error. This is fine if the indices are known at compile time, but not if they aren't.

An even worse situation is with `block_size`. A program can run for a long time before the time comes to resize, at which point either runtime exception or unpredictable behavior can occur.

So my question is:

> What is the (or one of the) Java idiomatic ways/design patterns to handle this? Am I making it too complicated (i.e. should I just stick with the `if` checks and get on with life)?

This question, I think, becomes less trivial in a less trivial context (than the example above). For instance, I wouldn't want to pollute my code with `if` checks. It would be nice to just delegate the task to a designated error handler, that should somehow be intrinsic to the type. For instance:

> Would it be more idiomatic to write a wrapper around the `int` type?
>   Is there an elegant/idiomatic way to use `Integer` for this purpose?

**EDIT**

I seem to be getting lots of comments on this (which I do appreciate), but many are not focused on the actual question. The array class is an example. I am asking for a general, idiomatic way to handle a general situation which may arise in many different contexts.

Comment: Even if Java had an unsigned int, half its values would be invalid indexes.

Comment: Fine. But that wasn't my question. And if Java did have unsigned integers, in this case perhaps it would also allow `unsigned int` as array indices, don't you think? Anyway, that wasn't my question.

Comment: Would you really want `blockSize` to be modifiable during the lifecycle of the object? I would set this in a constructor. Then you can check once at construction time and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the value is invalid.

Comment: @James_D Please see the edit.

Comment: The comment directly addresses your point about failing as early as possible. I am arguing that you can throw an exception for an invalid `blockSize` at construction time: you don't have to wait until the first time you resize.

Comment: FYI the invaluable [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library enables type-safe [unsigned arithmetic](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PrimitivesExplained#unsigned-support) including an [`UnsignedInteger`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInteger.html) type. I'll try not to on the bandwagon of "zomg why would you ever want that??!?!" but the reason people are expressing that is because it's not a commonly needed feature in Java-land. A little more digging may uncover cleaner alternatives, regardless of the use case.

Comment: Also, for the input sanitization use-case there's [`Preconditions`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained), which includes some helpful index-checking options.

Comment: @James_D James, I am not arguing with you, and I do appreciate your comments. However, your comment is more on the design of my example. That isn't what I'm asking for.

Comment: No, I disagree with your claim in the general case. I was using your example to make the point. As a general principle, you should strive to ensure that if code is going to fail it should fail as early as possible. You implicitly claim that the failure would only happen when the array has to be resized. That's not true: you can at least ensure failure when an invalid value is passed to `setBlockSize()` which is likely to be long before that. I would argue in this particular case you have the opportunity to fail long before that, as `blockSize` should be final.

Comment: @James_D Fair enough. See my comment to your answer. I appreciate an answer in the context of my own example.

Comment: We don't need any special libraries to figure out if an input is Unsigned or not, as this is a feature with Java 8 Integer and Long classes, as provided in my answer below.  It's a bit hard to understand what the OP is doing with "unsigned characters" or why.  I'm not sure why one would ever want to make a -# out of an array...?  I can see the values being unsigned, but not the List, Collection, Container, etc, having a unsigned size that's negative.  OP, can you clarify what exactly you need unsigned values for, and maybe a better answer will come up..  Hopefully mine is helpful to you.  GL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to bring you up to speed...

> Java does not have unsigned numeric types

Yes it does: `char` is a 16-bit unsigned numeric.

> I would like to keep track of the size of the array

No need. Java arrays have a `length` field that is infinitely more reliable than you keeping you own copy.

> Java will complain about the negative index and throw a compile-time error

No, it won't. You'll get a runtime error.

---

To answer your question, you have three basic choices:

- test `if (index < 0)` and throw an exception
- let the negative index through and let java throw its own runtime exception (GIGO)
- sanitize the input, eg `Math.abs(index)`

Comment: Thank you. This is essentially what I was looking for (i.e. a "Java-esque" way of handling something very common).

Comment: My preference is to do nothing. If code is silly enough to pass a negative value, I say let it explode. It will probably never happen, and it's not worth cluttering your code with protection against stupid input. Unless you are at a public interface, then a polite error message explaining the problem is appropriate.

Comment: Ok, technically `char` is an unsigned numeric type, but please don't jury-rig something that takes advantage of that fact :(

Comment: Integer and Long are also unsigned.

Comment: @Lasagna how then do you explain these compliable statements? `int i = -1;` and `long l = -1;`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to polute your code with multiple checks in each method, take a look at [guava library](https://github.com/google/guava). It actually prevents you from writing a lot of bicycles, providing common functionality, that is not (was not in the times when library was written) implemented in Java SE. For example it provides you with one line checks like:

`Preconditions.checkNotNull(obj);`

`Strings.isNullOrEmpty(str);`

BTW, part of this functionality is now implemented in Java 8 by Objects class.

Note: I feel really uncomfortable when talking about resizable array as a separate class in Java. Just note that exactly the same problem is solved by ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

The usual idiom (for a public API) is to check the validity of the arguments and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if invalid values are supplied.

```
public void setValueAt(int pos, int value) {
    // note that the actual check here may not be necessary, as 
    // (depending on how you implement this structure), the
    // subsequent code may throw essentially an identical exception anyway.
    // However, this demonstrates the idea:

    if (value < 0 || value > currentSize) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(pos + " is not in the range [0, "+currentSize+"]");
    }

    checkSize();
    array[pos]=value ;
}
```

As you observe in your comments about `blockSize`, you really want to try to throw exceptions as early as possible. For `blockSize`, I would not change the `blockSize` during the life cycle of the object. This means you can initialize `blockSize` in the constructor, and that gives you the opportunity to throw an exception at construction time:

```
public class List {
    private final int blockSize ;

    private final static int DEFAULT_BLOCL_SIZE = 20 ;

    public List(int blockSize) {
        if (blockSize <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("blockSize ("+blockSize+") must be positive");
        }
        this.blockSize = blockSize ;
    }

    public List() {
        this(DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE);
    }

    // ...
}
```

If you want `blockSize` to be modifiable, then the best you can do is validate when it is changed:

```
public class List {

    private int blockSize ;

    // ...

    public void setBlockSize(int blockSize) {
        if (blockSize <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("blockSize ("+blockSize+") must be positive");
        }
        this.blockSize = blockSize ;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note that how much you do this depends on the scope of the class you are writing. If you are not intending the class to be part of a public API, and you're only using it within the confines of your own immediate code, then these checks would probably be overkill: just write the code that uses this class in a way that doesn't provide nonsense values to the methods. Conversely, if you're writing a utility class for use across your entire organization, or a public API to be shared generally, it becomes more important to ensure sanity of the input.

Comment: Fair enough. This essentially answered my question. I was really curious whether there is anything else that Java programmers normally do (like write a wrapper around a given type; or if they are less paranoid and simply go with duck typing... personally, I prefer the latter).

Comment: It depends somewhat on the scenario. I would never create a wrapper to represent a non-negative integer for a case like this: too much overhead. OTOH for data types that have more complexity (dates, for example, though obviously there are existing classes for that), it makes sense to define a class that represents the data type and ensures you only ever have valid values of the data type (i.e. shift validation to the data type representation). There's sometimes a trade off between performance and robustness of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

For what it's worth, as of Java 8, both Longs, and Integers, can be `unsigned`

> int: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -231 and a maximum value of 231-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the int data type to represent an `unsigned` 32-bit integer, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 232-1. Use the Integer class to use int data type as an `unsigned` integer. See the section The Number Classes for more information. Static methods like `compareUnsigned`, `divideUnsigned` etc have been added to the Integer class to support the arithmetic operations for `unsigned` integers.
>
> long: The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The signed long has a minimum value of -263 and a maximum value of 263-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the long data type to represent an `unsigned` 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 264-1. Use this data type when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int. The Long class also contains methods like `compareUnsigned`, `divideUnsigned` etc to support arithmetic operations for `unsigned` long.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

It doesn't seem like there is a method to actually see if it's unsigned, or not, but you have a bunch of methods to figure things out, and the ability to create unsigned Integers.

---

As for

> For example, suppose I'm designing a dynamic array class. I would like to keep track of the size of the array, which I can declare as
>
> private int length
>
> In case an array needs to be resized, it should be resized by a set block_size, so I should also have

Arrays are not meant to be resized, even though you could get away with it..

Use an ArrayList instead

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList()<>;

list.size();  // gets current size if you wanted to keep track.
```